# Youtube in webview getting lag

Tags: webview, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using Webview for show youtube videos in my application, it's working great, the problem is that it's getting lag every load, for example if i'm go the bullet 10 seconds ahead, it's take like 5-10 seconds to reload the video, the same problem is if i get the bullet 10 seconds back

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you mean by "go the bullet 10 seconds ahead". Do you mean setting the playback to start a specific time? Also, if you're just playing YouTube from a WebView, why are you using the youtube-api tags?

Comment: I mean the seekbar bullet. what do you mean "why are you using the youtube-api tags" there is other way?

Comment: So when you drag the seekbar forward a bit, it takes a long time to load? Could this just be your own Internet or phone? And in terms of tags, I mean the tags you choose when you posted this question like "youtube-api", "youtube-data-api", and "youtube-api-v3", are those actually relevant tags if you're just playing a YouTube video from a `WebView`?

Comment: It's not Internet problem, becuase in chrome, when i'm running a video in youtube.com it's working fine, just in my application it's reload it for some reason. i taged it in youtube-api because i'm using youtube-api in my application